# Typescript Event Type Annotation

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

How could I provide the right type-annotation for this event?

**console:**

```
{
 originalEvent: InputEvent {isTrusted: true, data: " ", isComposing: false, 
 inputType: "insertText", dataTransfer: null, …}
 value: " "
 __proto__: Object
}
```

**Typescript code:**

```
const InputEvent = (event: ??? ) => console.log(event)
```

And is there a way to attach preventdefault function to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`InputEvent.ts` file

```
export class InputEvent {
   isTrusted: boolean;
   data: string;
   isComposing: boolean;
   inputType: string;
   dataTransfer: string;
   //and whatever more variables you have.
}
```

You can define it like this.

```
const InputEvent = (event: InputEvent ) => console.log(event);
```

Comment: Is there a way that I can attach a preventdefault function to this event?

Comment: Yeah define the `preventdefault : Function;` to the class `InputEvent`